# Webscrape an element out of a div on in a data-tip using vba

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I'm am trying to get an element in a web page. The HTML code is like that

```
<div>
 <span class=xxx data-tip=yyy>
 </span>
</div>
yyy
<div>
...
```

I want to get the string yyy.

What could I use?

I know how to get elements when they are between divs or spans. But I don't know what to do in this case.

Many tks

Comment: Try this `.querySelector("span[class='xxx']").getAttribute("data-tip")` to get the content within `data-tip` key.

Comment: OP - be aware querySelector will return the first matched node. Use querySelectorAll and index into returned nodeList if requiring a later match. Indexing starts at 0.